# In which interval (domain) does the $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\log^n(1+x)$ converge absolutely?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

In which interval (domain) does the sum

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\log^n(1+x)$$

converge absolutely?

I'm finding difficulty, but if I put $n=1$, then $\log(1+x) \le x$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\log^n(1+x)\le \sum x$ is divergent, definitely so I can say that $1$ will not be included in the interval (domain)...

Any hints/solutions will be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: I think the author meant $\log^n(1+x)=[\log(1+x)]^n$.

Comment: no,,same  question i have wriiten  @user10354138

Comment: i.e., you are supposed to interpret $\log^n$ like $\sin^n$ and not as the $n$-fold iteration of $\log$.

Comment: @user10354138,,,,okkss

Comment: why did you accept the answer if $\log^n(1+x)=(\log(1+x))^n?$

Comment: @zhw. i was very confused  ..so i accept

Comment: Once more:  Is $\log^n(1+x)=(\log(1+x))^n?$

Comment: @zhw.   For n=1  ..it   will hold  i mean  it will be true  ...for n= 2    idon't know

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

For $\log(1+x)$ to be well defined, $1+x>0$, so $x>-1$.

For $\log^2(1+x)=\log(\log(1+x))$ to be well defined, $\log(1+x)>0$, so $x>0$.

For $\log^3(1+x)$ to be well deefined, $\log^2(1+x)>0$, so $\log(1+x)>1$, so $x>e-1$.

For $\log^4(1+x)$ to be well deefined, $\log^3(1+x)>0$, so $\log^2(1+x)>1$, so $\log(1+x)>e$ so $x>e^e-1$.

Can you follow by induction?

I guess (I didn't do it) that for any $n\in{\mathbb N}$, $\log^n(1+x)$ is well defined iff $x>Exp^{n-2}(e)-1$ (where, $Exp^0(x)=1$ and $Exp^{-1}(x)=0$ and $Exp(x)=e^x$).