# Sum of logs $\log x + \log\log x +...$

Tags: summation

Is there a reduction for this infinite sum?

$$\log x + \log\log x + \log\log\log x +... = ?$$

for all $x > 0$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In which interval (domain) does the $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\log^n(1+x)$ converge absolutely?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2986738/in-which-interval-domain-does-the-sum-n-1-infty-logn1x-converge-ab)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The sum diverges with any reasonable interpretation of the logarithms. After all, $\log \log \cdots \log x$ is eventually a number that's less than $1$, and the next logarithm gives a negative result. After that, you get a complex result. Continuing in this manner, the terms do not tend to zero.